# Simple components of a semisimple $K$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional semisimple $K$-algebra. Since $A$ is semisimple, I can write it as a direct sum of its simple components: $$A=A_1\oplus\cdots\oplus A_m$$ where each $A_i$ is of the form Mat$_{n_i}(D^i)$ with $D^i$ a division ring and $n_i\ge1$, by Wedderburn's Theorem.

**Question:** Why is $D^i$ a $K$-algebra and $K\subset$  Cent$(D^i)?$ What is the easiest way to see this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's recall how you arrive at the $D^i$.

Each $D^i=End_{A_i}(S_i)$ where $S_i$ is a simple right ideal of $A_i$. Now $K$ is embedded in there too, consiering that $s\mapsto \lambda s$ is an $A_i$ homomorphism from $S_i$ into $S_i$ for each $\lambda\in K$.

If $f$ is any other endomorphism of $S_i$, then $(\lambda f)(s)=\lambda f(s)= f(\lambda s)=(f\lambda)(s)$ since $f$ is a homomorphism. This shows that $K$ is centrally embedded in $End_{A_i}(S_i)$.

Comment: So I take it that you are embedding $K$ into $D^i$ via $\lambda\mapsto l_\lambda$ where $l_\lambda$ is the mapping $s\mapsto \lambda s$? I can't see why this is an embedding since $S_i$ doesn't contain $1_{A_i}$.

Comment: @user68418 It's an embedding into $D^i=End(S_i)$, (not $A_i$) that we're looking at.

Comment: @user68418 If it helps, remember that $End_{A_i}(A_i)\cong A_i$ using the same idea, and that this mapping is just the restriction of that isomorphism to $K$.

Comment: Sorry but I'm a bit confused. Explicity, what is the embedding of $K$ into $D^i$? Regards

Comment: @user68418 It is *exactly* what you specified in your first comment. That comment lead me to believe you were thinking we were embedding into $A_i$, but I might have misunderstood. Why would $1_{A_i}$ have to be in $S_i$? $1_K$ is being mapped to $1_{D^i}$. There is no requirement about preserving ring identities here, anyhow.